# chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval - frameURL

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get the selected element to the sidebar pane in my chrome extension.
It's working fine if the page has no frames when the element is in the frame, it's not working.
As per the document I have to pass the frameURL, but how do I get the frame or Iframe URL?
Thank you.

Note: This issue is duplicate that was opened in 3 years ago, but still no solution there, so re-opening it again.

**In devtools.js**

```
chrome.devtools.panels.elements.createSidebarPane(name, (panel) => {
    // listen for the elements changes
    function updatePanel() {
        chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval("parseDOM($0)", {
            frameURL: // how to pass dynamic
            useContentScriptContext: true
        }, (result, exceptipon) => {
            if (result) {
                console.log(result)
            }
            if (exceptipon) {
                console.log(exceptipon)
            }
        });
    }
    chrome.devtools.panels.elements.onSelectionChanged.addListener(updatePanel);
});
```

Comment: There's no real solution. This API is just that bad. It also never could handle iframes without a URL or iframes with identical URLs. A possible workaround is to use a content script on all frames with DOM postMessage + document.activeElement recursion, but it'd be quite complicated especially if you also want to support ShadowDOM. The only proper alternative to all this hell is `chrome.debugger` API and CDP commands like Runtime.evaluate or Debugger.evaluateOnCallFrame.

Comment: Thank you for an instant reply,  I was looking at [Debugger.evaluateOnCallFrame](https://vanilla.aslushnikov.com/?Debugger.evaluateOnCallFrame), but could not find any example regarding this, and I am not pretty sure how to achieve this. 
If you have any please share, I have checked the famous chrome extension as you suggested in one of the posts, but that didn't help. 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this as well. I ended up needing to add a `content_script` on each page/iframe and a background page to help pass messages between devtools and content scripts.

The key bit is that in the devtools page, we should ask the `content_scripts` to send back what their current url is. For every content script that was registered, we can then call `chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval("setSelectedElement($0)", { useContentScriptContext: true, frameURL: msg.iframe } );`

Or in full:

```
chrome.devtools.panels.elements.createSidebarPane( "example", function( sidebar ) {
    const port = chrome.extension.connect({ name: "example-name" });
    // announce to content scripts that they should message back with their frame urls
    port.postMessage( 'SIDEBAR_INIT' );
    port.onMessage.addListener(function ( msg) {
        if ( msg.iframe ) {
            // register with the correct frame url
            chrome.devtools.panels.elements.onSelectionChanged.addListener(
                () => {
                    chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval("setSelectedElement($0)", { useContentScriptContext: true, frameURL: msg.iframe } );
                }
            );
        } else {
            // otherwise assume other messages from content scripts should update the sidebar
            sidebar.setObject( msg );
        }
    } );
  }
);
```

Then in the content_script, we should only process the event if we notice that the last selected element ([$0](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/utilities/#recent-many)) is different, since each frame on the page will also handle this.

```
let lastElement;
function setSelectedElement( element ) {
    // if the selected element is the same, let handlers in other iframe contexts handle it instead.
    if ( element !== lastElement ) {
        lastElement = element;
        // Pass back the object we'd like to set on the sidebar
        chrome.extension.sendMessage( nextSidebarObject( element ) );
    }
}
```

There's a bit of setup, including manifest changes, so see this PR for a full example:

https://github.com/gwwar/z-context/pull/21

Answer (score 0):

You can found url of the frame this way:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('iframe')[0].src
```

Assuming there is at lease one iframe.

Please note, you cannot use `useContentScriptContext: true`, as it will make the script execute as a context page (per documentation) and it will be in a separate sandboxed environment.

I had a slightly different problem, but it might be helpful for your case too, I was dynamically inserting an iframe to a page, and then tried to eval a script in it. Here the code that worked:

```js
let win = chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow
let code = `
(function () {
    let doc = window.document
    let insertFrm = doc.createElement('IFRAME')
    insertFrm.src = 'about:runner'
    body.appendChild(insertFrm)
})()`
win.eval(code, function (result, error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('Eror in insertFrame(), result:', result)
        console.error(error)
    } else {
        let code = `
        (function () {
            let doc = window.document
            let sc = doc.createElement('script')
            sc.src = '${chrome.runtime.getURL('views/index.js')}'
            doc.head.appendChild(sc)
        })()`
        win.eval(code, { frameURL: 'about:bela-runner' }, function (result, error) {
            if (error) {
                console.log('Eror in insertFrame(), result:', result)
                console.error(error)
            }
        })
    }
})
```